# SQL Server - transpose table and return temporary table with correct format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transpose

I have a non-modifiable SQL transaction that returns the following data:

```
----------------------
| NAME    |   VALUE  |
----------------------
| Amount   |    ...  |
----------------------
| Target   |    ...  |
----------------------
| Date     |    ...  |
----------------------
| Amount   |    ...  |
----------------------
| Target   |    ...  |
----------------------
| Date     |    ...  |
----------------------
```

e.g:

[image]

I want to format it so it looks like:

```
-----------------------------------------
|   Amount    |   Target    |   Date    |
-----------------------------------------
|    ...      |    ...      |   ...     |
-----------------------------------------
```

How would I go on accomplishing this?

The code I have is:

```
SELECT 
NAME, VALUE
FROM
function(@data)
/* AS PIVOT TABLE(...)*/
```

And I want to return a temporary table with the correct format.

Comment: How do you know which Amount, Target and Date go together? You have nothing in your sample data you can use for this. And your sample code...really?

Comment: @SeanLange It's just a transpose so the first 3 go together followed by the next 3 etc..

Comment: Right I get that. But for that to work you have to have something you can use to either group them together or provide an order. You have neither.

Comment: No pivot specialist here (at all), but maybe it's doable to add a rownumber and then group it by `FLOOR(row_num / 3)`?

Comment: @PeterB the challenge for ROW_NUMBER you need an order by. There is nothing here to define order. But yes I think what you are describing is reasonably close once the data is ordered.

Comment: @BDillan please show us the query or command that you use to retrieve the data. Maybe that can be converted to fill a temp table that has the needed row_number or e.g. an identity ID.

Comment: @PeterB https://pastebin.com/brxmHenK (as a preface this is the structure of the db I was given, I didn't decide the design so please don't question it or ask why I'm doing it this way) I have JSON objects stored in cells via a nvarchar(MAX) data type. I have a function called 'parseJSON' that gets these objects and returns a table like the one in the image. There is now way to index or lump together the elements as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this just use the select and replace #foo with your source of records, and ignore all of the setup unless you just want to run this specific example.

The grouping is based on position, and you can use floor((row_number() over (order by (select 1)) - 1) / 3) to get a group for every three rows.

```
create table #foo (
Name varchar(50),
StringValue varchar(50))


insert into #foo values ('Amount', '200')
insert into #foo values ('Target', '66')
insert into #foo values ('Date', '2017-1-1')
insert into #foo values ('Amount', '205')
insert into #foo values ('Target', '67')
insert into #foo values ('Date', '2017-3-1')


select 
    max(case when Name = 'Amount' then StringValue else null end) as Amount, 
    max(case when Name = 'Target' then StringValue else null end) as Target, 
    max(case when Name = 'Date' then StringValue else null end) as Date
from (
    select floor((row_number() over (order by (select 1)) - 1) / 3) as group_on, * from #foo 
    ) temp
group by group_on

drop table #foo
```

Comment: This works until that order by fails to return the rows in the same order.

Comment: I tried with like 75 data points, as long as you have all the values entered in the right order it seems to be working.  If you leave out a value then all bets are off.

Comment: It works sort of. Meaning that it returns data in the right order. But since there is nothing to signify the correct order this will work until the table is large enough and then suddenly it will stop working correctly and the data will be wrong. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx This is not a flaw with your answer, it is a flaw with design of the table. I gave this a +1 yesterday but need to point out the issue that will arise at some point for the OP.

Comment: If the OP could even add an identity column to the table they could use that as the ordering column and the issue would completely disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Sean, the row order is not guaranteed unless you actually specify an order by clause.  Generally speaking it will work to a point, but something to happen to re-arrange the data on the disk,  you could have a different order in the future.  Very dangerous I would say.